# Multiple interface with multiple wifi network

Tags: networking, wireless

My question is a bit of a tricky one.

My RPi has 2 wireless interfaces and I have 2 wireless routers with different SSIDs.
I am just looking for a configuration where the first wifi device always connects to the first AP and the second device to the other AP.

For example, like this:

```
wlan0 ------> ssid_one

wlan1 ------> ssid_two
```

Is it possible to solve this within the /etc/network/interfaces [+wpa_conf[s]] files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never tried this, but it should be simple.

Your `/etc/network/interfaces` probably contains a line like `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

Copy the wlan0 block.

I would make a new `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant2.conf` with the appropriate `SSID` etc.

You probably want to use `wpa-conf` instead of `wpa-roam`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I try it very quick and works neat, expect one thing:

When try `sudo ifdown wlan1` and `sudo ifup wlan1`, this two command works pretty well, without any problem, but for `sudo ifdown wlan0` I give some error, like `ifdown: interface wlan0 not configured`, but `sudo ifdown --f wlan0` works well with a little message: `RTNETLINK answers: No such process`. Anyway, thanks for the answer, and here is my `interfaces` file:
[link](http://pastebin.com/feaqKLa7)